# Экранирование запроса

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

Есть проблема с экранированием названий столбцов. Если я хочу сделать название столбца на русском то в запросе я должен это название заключить в кавычки. А как это сделать в c#? Вот что сделал я:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select brigade_number as '" + "Номер бригады" + "', count(status) as '" + "Задач выполнено" + "' from task_execution join brigade on task_execution.brigade_id = brigade.brigade_id where status = 'Выполнено' group by brigade_number having count(*)>0", con); Но в итоге это даёт только название в апострофах. А нужны кавычки. Пробовал по 2 апострофа сделать но это тоже не даёт положительного результата. Подскажите пожалуйста как это нужно сделать. Спасибо заранее.
```

Comment: OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select brigade_number as ""Номер бригады"", count(status) as ""Задач выполнено"" from task_execution join brigade on task_execution.brigade_id = brigade.brigade_id where status = 'Выполнено' group by brigade_number having count(*)>0", con);

Попробуй так...

Comment: А экранировать `"` с помощью обратных косых `"select 1 as \"Номер бригады\""` в С# случайно нельзя. Ну или да, удваиванием  кавычек

Comment: можно и специально :)

Comment: И вот гугл по запросу "C# строка" дает ссылку где это все объяснено https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228362.aspx

Comment: А зачем столбцы на русском? плохая идея, имхо.